# Getting Mainland country borders for France in Overpass Turbo without colonies

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

Does anyone have experience with whether there is a query argument for overpass-turbo to receive only mainland borders for e.g. France, without all the colonial islands scattered around the world?

My ideal scenario would be to only get the french mainland borders and maybe also Corsica.

Thank you.

I have been using in [Overpass Turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/):

`[out:json]; rel[admin_level=2]["ISO3166-1"="FR"]; out geom;`

to get all of France (which unfortunately includes all the hundreds of colonies)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is asked (duplicate) and answered here:

https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/86154/overpass-query-for-getting-only-mainland-country-boarders-no-colonies

> So your overpass query would look like:

```
[out:json]; rel[admin_level=3][name="France métropolitaine"]; out geom;
```

> See: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1nOq